# JPQL: Access inherited Attributes in a Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I've implemented this with JPA (Eclipse Link)
[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X5DU.png) (I can't post pictures yet)

Now I'm setting up a query that shows me all the semesters where a specific teacher has lessons.

```
Query query2 = em
   .createQuery("FROM Semester s, IN (s.lesson) l, IN(l.lessonTeacher) lT1 WHERE lT1.teacher.lastname = :lastname");
query.setParameter("lastname", "Spooner");
List<Semester> resultList2 = query.getResultList(); 
for(Semester s : resultList2){
    System.out.println(s.getname());
}
```

My problem is this: lT1.teacher.lastname = :lastname
I can't access the inherited Attribute.

```
The state field path 'lT1.teacher.lastname' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Can any1 help?

Comment: You will have to join the Teacher table using 'lT1.teacher', like you have done for 'l.lessonTeacher'.

Comment: FWIW JPQL starts with "SELECT s"; that posted is invalid/non-portable. Nobody wants you to post "pictures" of classes. Post the relevant CODE!

Comment: Please show us the code of the classes

Comment: Priyesh solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the inherited attribute. You will have to add another join(to the `Teacher` table) to your query like below to solve this:

```
Query query2 = em
   .createQuery("FROM Semester s, IN (s.lesson) l, IN(l.lessonTeacher) lT1, lT1.teacher t WHERE t.lastname = :lastname");
query.setParameter("lastname", "Spooner");
List<Semester> resultList2 = query.getResultList(); 
for(Semester s : resultList2){
    System.out.println(s.getname());
}
```

Comment: Why?  lT1.teacher.lastname should perform the same inner join as using "lT1.teacher t" in the from clause.

Comment: JPA does not do that explicitly I think. Whenever I have tried that it has failed to join it explicitly and I had to join the property explicitly.

Comment: It should according to the specification, and  is only an issue with collection references..  Using a . between references forces an inner join between the entities.